# Knife command output in human readable format

Tags: chef-infra, knife

So I am trying to get filesystem sizes using a knife command as below.
As is, I can see the sizes in kb; is there a way I can convert them to human readable values (Mb or Gb) in knife commands itself? Or may be parse and then convert?
My First preference would be an in-line modification rather than converting it into a script. I am fetching many more values from the knife command , hence programmatically it would be a bit difficult

```
knife search node 'hostname:MyHostName' -a filesystem.by_mountpoint./apps.kb_size -a filesystem.by_mountpoint./apps.kb_used -Fjson
{
  "results": 1,
  "rows": [
    {
      "MyHostName": {
        "filesystem.by_mountpoint./apps.kb_size": "1998672",
        "filesystem.by_mountpoint./apps.kb_used": "760672"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```